# Can I improve this Pig-Latin converter?

Tags: java, string, substring, translation

I'm brand-spanking new to Java and I made this little translator for PigLatin.

```
package stringmanipulation;

public class PigLatinConverter {
    public String Convert(String word){
        int position = 0;
        if (!IsVowel(word.charAt(0))) {
            for (int i= 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (IsVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            String first = word.substring(position, word.length());
            String second = word.substring(0, position) + "ay";

            return first + second;
        } else {
            return word + "way";
        }
    }

    public boolean IsVowel(char c){
        if (c == 'a')
            return true;
        else if(c == 'e')
            return true;
        else if(c == 'i')
            return true;
        else if(c == 'o')
            return true;
        else if(c == 'u')
            return true;
        else
            return false;        
    }
}
```

Are there any improvements I can make?

Are there any nifty Java tricks that are in the newest Java version I might not be aware of? I come from a C# background.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not remove the piglatin tag, it's relevant to the question.

Comment: I disagree, the tag `piglatin` is totally irrelevant, but I'll leave you in peace.

Comment: this type of question belongs on code review

Comment: The piglatin tag is related to Apache Pig's language layer. By reading the definition of the tag you will see that is is not relevent to String manipulation in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rewrite `isVowel(char ch)` as follows:

```
return "aeiou".indexOf(ch) != -1;
```

And I'd write the following instead:

```
// String first = word.substring(position, word.length());
   String first = word.substring(position);
```

I'd also rename method names to follow coding convention.

And of course, being me, I'd also use regex instead of `substring` and `for` loop.

```
System.out.println("string".replaceAll("([^aeiou]+)(.*)", "$2$1ay"));
// ingstray
```

#### References

- [Java Coding Convention - Naming Convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html)

Comment: This is the sexyness I was looking for. I'll test it out. EDIT: I get an error: Required: CharSequence Found: Char

Comment: @Sergio: sorry, use `indexOf(char)` instead.

Comment: +1 for the "being me, I'd also use regex" (and the rest of the answer of course). Made me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I don't know Java.*

Inverted logic is confusing please write your `if` statement as such:

```
    if (IsVowel(word.charAt(0))) {
        return word + "way";
    } else {
        for (int i= 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

        // ...

        return first + second;
    }
```

You can even drop the `else`.

`IsVowel` may need to be private.  It can also be rewritten using a single `||` chain, or as a `"".indexOf` (or whatever it is in Java).

Your `for` logic can be simplified int a short `while`:

```
        while (position < word.length() && !IsVowel(word.charAt(position)) {
            ++position;
        }
```

Comment: I agree with the inverted logic. That while statement seems a bit convoluted in my opinion.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, Java may have something like `.indexOf` which takes a callback as an argument (and you'd use `IsVowel` as the callback), which turns the loop into a call and a check.

Comment: I *much* prefer "returning early"; more levels of indentation makes the code harder to read. Apparently, nested conditionals are also the main source of bugs.

Comment: @tc., While I agree, I find it's more personal style and not something which is that objective.  (See: single-`return`-per-function advocates.)

Comment: presumably those are the same people who think "goto"  is always evil, whereas I think unnecessarily embedding flow control into your data is evil (and a pain for your compiler to optimize).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete rewrite that makes the code more readable if you know how to read regex:

```
String[] words =
    "nix scram stupid beast dough happy question another if".split(" ");

for (String word : words) {
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", word,
        ("w" + word).replaceAll(
            "w(qu|[^aeiou]+|(?<=(w)))([a-z]*)",
            "$3-$1$2ay"
        )
    );
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/KhApq)):

```
nix -> ix-nay
scram -> am-scray
stupid -> upid-stay
beast -> east-bay
dough -> ough-day
happy -> appy-hay
question -> estion-quay
another -> another-way
if -> if-way
```

Note that `question` becomes `estion-quay`, which is the correct translation according to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin). In fact, the above words and translations are taken from the article.

The way the regex work is as follows:

- First, all words are prefixed with `w` just in case it's needed
- Then, skipping that `w`, look for either `qu` or a non-empty sequence of consonants. If neither can be found, then the actual word starts with a vowel, so grab the `w` using capturing lookbehind
- Then just rearrange the components to get the translation

That is:

```
"skip" dummy w
|
w(qu|[^aeiou]+|(?<=(w)))([a-z]*)   -->  $3-$1$2ay
 \                2\_/ /\______/
  \_________1_________/    3
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Character class:`[…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Alternation: `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Repetition:`+`,`*`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Lookaround:`(?<=…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and [Capturing:`(…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: I start to see ASCII art in your answers, an upside down truck in this one :) +1 for art.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is well over a year old, but I thought I would put my modification of it. There are several improvements in this code.

```
public String convert(String word)
{
    int position = 0;
    while(!isVowel(word.charAt(position)))
    {
        ++position;
    }
    if(position == 0)
    {
        return word + "-way";
    }
    else if(word.charAt(0) == 'q')
    {
        ++position;
    }
    return word.substring(position) + "-" + word.substring(0, position) + "ay";
}
public boolean isVowel(char character) 
{
    switch(character)
    {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

First the code will find the position of the first vowel, and then jump out of the loop. This is simpler than using a for loop to iterate through each letter and using break; to jump out of the loop. Secondly, this will match all the testcases on the Wikipedia site. Lastly, since chars are actually a limited range int, a switch statement can be used to improve performance and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an improvement as such, but Java convention dictates that methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Sergio seems to be a C# guy. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: I'm not hating, I really want to learn Java. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm years removed from Java, but overall, your code looks fine. If you wanted to be nitpicky, here are some comments:

- Add comments. It doesn't have to follow the Javadoc specification, but at least explicitly describe the accepted argument and the expected return value and perhaps give some hint as to how it works (behaving differently depending on whether the first character is a vowel)
- You might want to catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which I think might happen if you pass it a zero length string.
- Method names should be lower case.
- `IsVowel` can be rewritten `return c == 'a' || c == 'e'` and so on. Due to short-circuiting, the performance in terms of number of comparisons should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework? If so, tag it as such.

- Unclear what expected behaviour is for "honest" or "ytterbium".
- It doesn't respect capitals ("Foo" should turn into "Oofay", and AEIOU are also vowels).
- It crashes if you pass in the empty string.